# Image in HTML table goes to top of page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am writing a PHP script and when I run the output in HTML the image in the cell is at the top of the page. I am using a table in HTML and I tried to put the image in its own cell but still goes to the top of the page. I think it may be because I got some CSS code that may be interfering with it. This page is still a work in progress.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    h1 {
        background-color: orange;
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 40px;
    }
    p {
        background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    }
    img {
        float: right;
        margin: -250 850 10px 10px;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-top: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1><b><i>WEATHER CHIPMUNK</i></b></h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>WeatherChipmunk</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"onclick=parent.location="index.php">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            
            <li><a href="#asdfasdfasdf" onclick=parent.location="City.php">   CURRENT WEATHER   </a></li>
        
         <li><a href="#casdfasdf" onclick=parent.location="PastWeatherScreen.php">   WEATHER RECORDS   </a></li>
         <li><a href="#asdfasdf" onclick=parent.location="StatsInfoScreen.php">   WEEKLY STATISTICS   </a></li>
           
       <!-- <li><a href="#news" onclick=parent.location="fillPast.php">  fill past table   </a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><a href="#news" onclick=parent.location="fillForecast.php">   fill forecast table   </a></li> -->
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      
    <div class="container">
    
    </div>
    <select name=citySelection value=''>Select City...</option><option value=1>Spartanburg</option><option value=2>Greenville</option><option value=3>Rock_Hill</option><option value=4>Columbia</option><option value=5>Myrtle_Beach</option><option value=6>Charleston</option><option value=7>Charlotte</option><option value=8>Asheville</option><option value=9>Wilmington</option><option value=10>Raleigh</option><option value=11>Greensboro</option></select> <br><br>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
    <td><img src="http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_tstorms.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" style="float:left;"</img></td>
       <td>Thursday Night  Temp: 52 ˚F<br>nt_tstorms <br>  Prep: 80 % <br> </td> 
    
    
    
    
    
    
        
    
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're closing your HTML (`</body></html>`)  before outputting your select box, and then attempting to close both a second time s well. This is invalid syntax, and may be interfering with your CSS.

Comment: hello there, what's the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code in two sections (one near the top and the other near the bottom). From what I've understood, you want the image to be right-aligned within the cell, hence the `text-align: right;` within `td.image` CSS.

You may also want to check the sequence of opening/closing tags, such as `<html>` and `<body>`, since there are also a few errors there.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    background-color: orange;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}
p {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
/*** CODE HAS BEEN CHANGED HERE ***/
td.image {
  text-align: right;
}
table, th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><b><i>WEATHER CHIPMUNK</i></b></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <!-- *** Why is a new html tag entered here? *** -->
<head>
  <title>WeatherChipmunk</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"onclick=parent.location="index.php">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#asdfasdfasdf" onclick=parent.location="City.php">   CURRENT WEATHER   </a></li>
        <li><a href="#casdfasdf" onclick=parent.location="PastWeatherScreen.php">   WEATHER RECORDS   </a></li>
        <li><a href="#asdfasdf" onclick=parent.location="StatsInfoScreen.php">   WEEKLY STATISTICS   </a></li>
      <!-- <li><a href="#news" onclick=parent.location="fillPast.php">  fill past table   </a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><a href="#news" onclick=parent.location="fillForecast.php">   fill forecast table   </a></li> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
</div>
<select name=citySelection value=''>Select City...</option><option value=1>Spartanburg</option><option value=2>Greenville</option><option value=3>Rock_Hill</option><option value=4>Columbia</option><option value=5>Myrtle_Beach</option><option value=6>Charleston</option><option value=7>Charlotte</option><option value=8>Asheville</option><option value=9>Wilmington</option><option value=10>Raleigh</option><option value=11>Greensboro</option></select> <br><br>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <!-- *** CODE HAS BEEN CHANGED HERE *** -->
    <td class="image"><img src="http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_tstorms.gif" alt="W3Schools.com"</img></td>
    <td>Thursday Night  Temp: 52 ˚F<br>nt_tstorms <br>  Prep: 80 % <br> </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, some of the code was written by another person and half of the code is generated by a PHP script so that's why the layout is a little funny. Do I need to put </img> at the end of the image code?

Comment: I would recommend always closing off tags in HTML, for example `<img src="..." />`, `<br />`, etc.

Comment: Ok I see the problem is that another script is added into this one with <?php include 'DropDownNavBar2.php' so that is the reason for having two headers and body.

Comment: One other thing is, how can I change the width of the cell the image is in to make it shorter?

Comment: Use `width: 100px;` (or whatever value you want) within `td.image` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a few errors. The most noticeable one is the body and the html tag placements. Also, your option and img tag were also wrongly placed

img tag -

```
<td><img src="http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_tstorms.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" style="float:left;"></td>
```

option tag -

```
<select name=citySelection value=''>Select City...
  <option value=1>Spartanburg</option>
  <option value=2>Greenville</option>
  <option value=3>Rock_Hill</option>
  <option value=4>Columbia</option>
  <option value=5>Myrtle_Beach</option>
  <option value=6>Charleston</option>
  <option value=7>Charlotte</option>
  <option value=8>Asheville</option>
  <option value=9>Wilmington</option>
  <option value=10>Raleigh</option>
  <option value=11>Greensboro</option>
</select>
```

Here is the jfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/